# Fetch zip file from the web and decompress it in Go

Tags: go, zip

How can I fetch a zip archived file from the Web and decompress it in Go? It looks like `archive/zip` package provides a set of tools to parse the zipped file. However, in order to decompress the zipped file, I have to use `zip.OpenReader`, which takes the filename as string.

So how can I fetch the zipped file from the Web, and put it into the above function as string...? Or maybe do I have to first fetch the file and put it in one of the directories of my filesystem, and then read it?

Comment: You will need to first download the file and store on the local file system then use the zip.OpenReader function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that in order to decompress a zip, you need to be able to seek to arbitrary locations. This means that unless you want to do something fancy, it either needs to be a local file or be completely in memory.

Assuming you have downloaded the zip and have it in a `[]byte`, you want to do something like:

```
zipReader := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(zipData), len(zipData))
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I like to ask one more question then - do most other languages take the similar step as what you suggest? In other words, is this the design of Go, or do I have to take the similar thing in whatever languages I use? I have some casual experience in other languages such as Python, but have never handle zip-related operations.